# set style.listStyleImage with a var

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting listStyleImage with a for loop.

This works

```
li.style.listStyleImage = 'url("../images/video/bcg.png")';
```

This does not

```
var _image = "../images/video/bcg.png";
li.style.listStyleImage = 'url(_image)';
```

nor this

```
var _image = "../images/video/bcg.png";
li.style.listStyleImage = 'url("_image")';
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `_image` varaible:

```
li.style.listStyleImage = 'url(' + _image + ')';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Now that I look at it, it makes sense.

Comment: Glad to help, I would be grateful for your aswer accept and an upvote :)

Comment: I tried but Since this is my first question it wont let me.

Comment: Well, you should be able to accept the ansewer after 15 minutes from asking the question (by the way you will also get `+2` reputation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), but nevermind.